# How do I retrieve values in an Object and covert them into different variable types?

Tags: c#, json, linq

I'm retrieving some values through Json and I convert them into object. Next I want to pass them in to the database through DBAccess.cs script. This is done through a MVC. All I wanted is to get the values stored in that object

Here's the controller.cs:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostRegister([FromBody] dynamic register)
{
    try
    {
        Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject employeeRes = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)register.employeedetails;

        var employee = employeeRes.ToObject<Employee>();

        var inserted_id = uMgt.insertRegDetail(employeeRes);
        int nid = (int)inserted_id;

        return Ok("success");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return Ok("fail");
    }
}
```

Here's the userManagement.cs

```
public int insertRegDetail(Employee emp)
{
            try 
            {
                var new_id = db.PassRegistraiondetails("new_insert_detail", emp.Fname, emp.Lname, Convert.ToDateTime(emp.Date_of_Birth), emp.Nic, emp.Gender, emp.Email, emp.Mobile_no, Convert.ToInt32(emp.Department_name), emp.Designation, Convert.ToDateTime(emp.Date_of_join));

                return (new_id);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
              Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
              return (0);
            }
}
```

And finally the DBAccess.cs

```
public int PassRegistraiondetails(string spName, string FName, string LName, DateTime dob, string nic, string Gender, string email, int tel, int id, string Designation, DateTime doj)
{
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                SqlParameter param;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = spName;

                param = new SqlParameter("@fname", SqlDbType.NChar);
                param.Value = FName;
                param.IsNullable = true;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

                param = new SqlParameter("@lname", SqlDbType.NChar);
                param.Value = LName;
                param.IsNullable = true;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

                param = new SqlParameter("@DOB", SqlDbType.Date);
                param.Value = dob;
                param.IsNullable = true;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

                param = new SqlParameter("@gender", SqlDbType.NChar);
                param.Value = Gender;
                param.IsNullable = true;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

                param = new SqlParameter("@email", SqlDbType.NChar);
                param.Value = email;
                param.IsNullable = true;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

                param = new SqlParameter("@mobile_no", SqlDbType.Int);
                param.Value = tel;
                param.IsNullable = true;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

                param = new SqlParameter("@designation", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                param.Value = Designation;
                param.IsNullable = true;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

                param = new SqlParameter("@date_of_join", SqlDbType.Date);
                param.Value = doj;
                param.IsNullable = true;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

                param = new SqlParameter("@nic", SqlDbType.NChar);
                param.Value = nic;
                param.IsNullable = true;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

                param = new SqlParameter("@dept_id", SqlDbType.Int);
                param.Value = id;
                param.IsNullable = false;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@new_id", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    this.OpenConnection();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    int ID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@new_id"].Value);
                    this.CloseConnection();
                    return ID;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return (0);
            }
}
```

The error I get now is that:

> Cannot convert Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject to Doman.Employee

<-- Here domain is a base class

How do I resolve this. Hep would be great appreciated

Here's my JSON data

```
{ "employeedetails": 
     {"Fname":"awad","Lname":"adadad","Date_of_Birth":"09/13/2016",
      "Nic":"asdasdasd","Gender":"Male",
      "Email":"asQsa@c","Mobile_no":"1234234234",
      "Designation":"asdasd","Date_of_join":"09/27/2016",
      "Department_name":"1"
     }
}
```

Here's my Employee.cs

```
namespace Efutures.HR.LeaveManagement.Domain
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Empid { get; set; }
        public string Fname { get; set; }
        public string Lname { get; set; }
        public string Date_of_Birth { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int Mobile_no { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public string Date_of_join { get; set; }
        public string Nic { get; set; }
        public string Department_name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: please give an example of your Json data, also show us the Employee class and how you're assigning the values from the Json to the Employee properties \ objects

Comment: @SimonPrice The required details are given :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ashane Alvis, If you see the JSON you are getting it has a property called `employeedetails` in which you have the object containing the employee information.

So you need a class let's say `Employee` having a property called `employeedetails` which is of type let's say `EmployeeDetails` that is having the rest of the properties in the main property `employeedetails` in the given JSON.

Check the below code snippet it will convert the JSON you've provided into an employee object.

```
namespace TestProject
{
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = "{\"employeedetails\":{\"Fname\":\"awad\",\"Lname\":\"adadad\",\"Date_of_Birth\":\"09/13/2016\",\"Nic\":\"asdasdasd\",\"Gender\":\"Male\",\"Email\":\"asQsa @c\",\"Mobile_no\":\"1234234234\",\"Designation\":\"asdasd\",\"Date_of_join\":\"09/27/2016\",\"Department_name\":\"1\"}}";
            var employee = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(Employee));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public EmployeeDetails employeedetails { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmployeeDetails
    {
        public string Empid { get; set; }

        public string Fname { get; set; }

        public string Lname { get; set; }

        public string Date_of_Birth { get; set; }

        public string Gender { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public int Mobile_no { get; set; }

        public string Designation { get; set; }

        public string Date_of_join { get; set; }

        public string Nic { get; set; }

        public string Department_name { get; set; }
    }
}
```